# Ощущение липкости или прилипания?

Tags: значение-слов

Как правильно сказать: ощущение липкости или ощущение прилипания?

Answer (score 3):

Это два разных осязательных ощущения. Ощущение липкости возникает от соприкосновения с вязким веществом, а ощущение прилипания - когда кажется, что напр. рука прилипла к чему-то, от чего её трудно оторвать.